# Interactive transcript for Youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, html5-video, caption, webvtt

I am working on a Youtube video site and would like to implement interactive transcript feature like this one: http://demo.jwplayer.com/iframes/interactive-transcript/ (I have video transcript and caption files, in SRT and WebVTT format. I will **not** use Youtube's machine transcribed transcript.)

I did a research online. It appears that there is no free plug-in/module that can do this. There are some paid options, such as Captionbox (http://speakertext.com/captionbox) ,3rdMediea, SubPly (http://www.subply.com/en/Products/InterActiveTranscript.htm BTW: this is the best I have found so far. It loads transcript in different languages on the fly). I am reluctant to use these paid options, primarily because I do not want to rely on a single provider.

Can someone please advise me a better option?

Thank you.

Comment: How did you get this resolved? I want to achieve the same, just don't wanna upload my video and transcript to JWPlayer cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write your own solution:

1. Read YouTube API Dosc:
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1
2. Check getCurrentTime()

Read transcript from file/database/hiddendiv and display it if getCurrentTime == textTime from your transcript then just highlight it (like in captionbox example).